# Как подписаться на два observable разного типа за раз? rxjava

Tags: android, kotlin, rxjava

У меня есть два observable разного типа.

```
val urlContent = contentRepo.getUrlContent(urls).toObservable()

val isConnected = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).flatMap {
    internetConnectionRepo.isInternetOnline()
}
```

urlContent типа `Observable<List<String>>`,
а isConnected типа `Observable<Boolean>`.
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы isConnected действовал, пока не получу urlContent. При этом, это всё находится в usecase, который должен вернуть `List<String>`. Я пробовал написать:

```
return isConnected.takeUntil(urlContent)
```

Но тогда usecase возвращает `Observable<Boolean>`.
Как я могу получить результат urlContent?

Comment: Что значит "чтобы isConnected действовал, пока не получу urlContent"? Зачем ему действовать (и что вы подразумеваете под действовал?), почему бы просто не возвращать urlContent?

Comment: в коде написано что он каждую секунду выполняет получение статуса подключения к интернету. и по условию задачи, это нужно делать пока я не получу urlContent